# Escape variables with filenames that have spaces

Tags: bash, pngcrush

I'm using this line to batch my `pngcrush`, yet my files contain spaces, which get's placed literally into `$line`, making them get skipped as they aren't valid paths:

```
ls *.png | while read line; do pngcrush -brute $line compressed/$line; done
```

How can I make $line become escape like this filename `Button - Users.png` would be replaced with `Button\ -\ Users.png`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Don't parse the output of `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs). Use a `for` loop here instead.

```
for f in *.png; do
    pngcrush -brute "$line" compressed/"$line"
done
```

Answer (score -2):

Simply enclose variables in double-quotes. It's a good practice ever:

```
ls *.png | while read line; do pngcrush -brute "$line" "compressed/$line"; done
```